# How to post data back to my node.js rest api server using jQuery Ajax post method

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, rest

I have succeeded in posting data from my front end to the server, using this code;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('I was clicked!')
        postData()
    })


    let formData = {
        name: 'Samson Ugwu', 
        email: 'ugwu@example.com', 
        password: 'Samson!!@@@'
    }

    function postData() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/users',
            headers: {
             'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            crossDomain: true,
            cache: false,
            data: JSON.stringify(formData),
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data)
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
        });
    }

});
```

But each time I try sending the data back to the server via a form that a user will fill instead of explicitly writing out the name, email and password in the code I get this error message in my console:

```
{errors: {…}, _message: "User validation failed", message: "User validation failed: name: Path `name` is requi…required., password: Path `password` is required.", name: "ValidationError"}errors:email:kind: "required"message: "Path `email` is required."name: "ValidatorError"path: "email"properties:message: "Path `email` is required."path: "email"type: "required"value: ""__proto__: Objectvalue: ""__proto__: Objectname: {message: "Path `name` is required.", name: "ValidatorError", properties: {…}, kind: "required", path: "name", …}password: {message: "Path `password` is required.", name: "ValidatorError", properties: {…}, kind: "required", path: "password", …}__proto__: Objectmessage: "User validation failed: name: Path `name` is required., email: Path `email` is required., password: Path `password` is required."name: "ValidationError"_message: "User validation failed"__proto__: Object
```

What might be the cause and how can I fix this.

Comment: We'd need the code in the backend to help finding out why the error message is being printed. Maybe it expects a different structure?

Comment: Here is the code ``` const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
```

Comment: Is that the entire schema? I only see the name field, yet you are attempting to send an email and a password as well... What happens if you send only a name? (e. g. if you comment out the email and the password)

Comment: Every other thing is correct @Invizio, I only need to know why my data is not submitting to the server each time I use an htm form tag to send data to the server.

Comment: I ran your code against a test server and it responded with all the given fields. If you press F12, go in the Network tab, and refresh, you should be able to find your AJAX call in the list that'll appear. It'll tell you what the browser actually sends, and what the server responded (you already have the latter). Does it send all the information?